# How to enable JupyterHub in MicroK8s's Kubeflow?

Tags: kubernetes, jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub, kubeflow, microk8s

a kubeflow user beginner here.

I'm following a tutorial on how to setup Kubeflow in a Ubuntu (VM) on my personal laptop using this tutorial: [kubeflow-on-microk8s](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/distributions/microk8s/kubeflow-on-microk8s/). The problem is, when I'm trying to access JupyterHub under the menu "Notebooks" an error always occured:

[image: JupyterhubError]

```
{ 
  log": "The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.", 
  "status": 404, 
  "success": false, 
  "user": "admin" 
}
```

All jupyter's instance appear to be nominal and kubeflow-UI working except all related to jupyter's instance:

[image: jupyter's instance]

I can't seem to know what is happening here. I have spent days to find solution on this, nothing ever mentioned.

I have been using miniKF (Rok + Kubeflow + minikube) and they are actually fine, but I prefer to have bare implementation and local machine rather from other solution (i.e., paid services) so please don't mention about using miniKF.

Thanks

Comment: What URL is it requesting (if you can see in the Network tab of developer tools in your browser)? Perhaps it's a mis-configuration ... checking that against the ConfigMaps in the kubeflow namepspace may be a start.